How to find out whether the owner of a google drive folder is a personal email or business domain?
I've been asked to upload personal id to a Google Drive folder (via Upworks a freelance marketplace) and I wish to confirm that the owner of the folder comes from a specific business domain. Is that possible and how can one do that?

Sounds a bit sketchy. You are right to be careful.

You can simply find the file in your "Shared with me" page or in "Suggested", right click on it, and there will be an option "Block example@gmail.com". Anybody can easily see the address of a file owner now.

The OP has been provided a folder link not a file. Can you [edit] your answer to clarify if that is what you mean.
